# SSRS concurrency issue

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I use a server and multiple clients. When clients want to create a report with Reporting Services they call a webservice of the server and the server calls an another webservice of the report services. The problem is that when two clients calls the same report (for different dataset, but same report definition) same time then sometimes report content are changed between the two client, or it seems the second webservice calls report with default parameters but I don't know why. I tried to lock server report calls on serverside but no luck. Is it a concurrency issue?

```
SyncLock _lockerObject
    serviceReporting = New WebServiceFactory().GetReportingWebservice()
    execInfo = serviceReporting.LoadReport(folderName & reportName, Nothing)
    serviceReporting.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, Nothing)
    result = serviceReporting.Render(format, Nothing, Nothing, encoding, mimeType, warnings, streamIDs)
End SyncLock
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for different dataset", do you mean different data based on the report parameters?

Comment: @RossBush Yes. I call the report with two different object ID which is the primary key in the table. Other data like formatting pattern, etc. is the same. Defined stored procedure in the report gets all data of the object. I wrote out the parameter count and values for both thread but they are the same (except the object ID).